# Class membership of Ray-AABB intersection function

Tags: c++, oop, membership, aabb, ray

I'm writing code for mouse picking in 3D space. So far I've made Ray and AABB classes. What I need is a function for Ray-AABB intersecting. I know how to write it and make it work, my question is which class should define said funcion? Should it be a member of Ray or AABB, both, neither? What are the best practices for object oriented approach?

For me it makes the most sense to implement that function as a member of "engine" class, more like a procedure rather than a function. However I want my code to be truly object oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: **neither**.

- **Ray**: Structure (Members: *Start*, *End*)
- **AABB**: Structure (Members: *Position*, *Size*).

**Ray-AABB intersection** method could be in a `Physics` or `Intersection` class (Depends on your actual context) as static methods (Or functions in a namespace, depends on your coding convention).

Object oriented is fine, but it doesn't mean that everything you create should be a class.

Data oriented is a very good approach (CPU friendly with less [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss)).

**EDIT:** A good coding rule is to think your things independently, meaning that the `AABB` implementation shouldn't be dependent on the `Ray` implementation.